# Как зациклить определенную строчку кода в Java

Tags: java

Во время изучения java по книге написал код и хотел бы зациклить лишь строчку, которая выводит текст пользователю на экран

```
class PhraseGeneration{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] wordListOne = {"small", "big", "enormous", "giant"};
    String[] wordListTwo = {"green", "red", "blue", "pink"};
    String[] wordListThree = {"umbrella", "doll", "coat", "building"};
    int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
    int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
    int threeLength = wordListThree.length; 
     int rand1 = (int)(Math.random() * oneLength);
     int rand2 = (int)(Math.random() * twoLength);
     int rand3 = (int)(Math.random() * threeLength);
      String pharse = wordListOne [rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];
        while (true)
          System.out.print("I'm really dissapointed by that code " + pharse);
}
```

}

ниже пример, как я пытался вывести именно эту строку в цикл, так же я пробовал перенести out.print в отдельные фигурные скобки, но в этом случае программа не могла найти int pharse

Элемент списка

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вы хотите в цикле генерировать фразы:

```
while (true) {
    int rand1 = (int)(Math.random() * oneLength);
    int rand2 = (int)(Math.random() * twoLength);
    int rand3 = (int)(Math.random() * threeLength);
    String pharse = wordListOne [rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];
        
    System.out.print("I'm really dissapointed by that code " + pharse);
}
```

Comment: в случае с ответом выше программа перестает выводить на экран сгенерированные фразы

Comment: Она выводит, только все в одну строку и вы этого просто не видите в конце строки. Замените `print` на `println` и тогда каждая фраза будет на новой строке.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все заработало